# crystal report 10: what are the differences between "memo" fields and normal "string" fields

Tags: crystal-reports

In crystal report 10, under field explorer menù, every "string" source fields have relatives "Memo" fields. What are the differences between these two type of fields ?
Because in some report the "string" field is truncated and i must use the relative "memo" type to see the entire content of that field. But i don't know why. Can anyone help me to understand the diffenreces of these two type of fields and when i have to chose one insted of other.

Thank's

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe in the past, the text functions in Crystal were limited to strings with a length less than or equal to 255 Characters, unless you were checking for nulls

Crystal introduced Memo fields to get around this limitation.  So with the memo data type you can perform searches and manipulation on strings greater than 255 characters in length.

Comment: so if i always use "memo" fields when i have a possible long string is only a benefit. Right ?

Comment: I think the answer is, it depends.  If you know you only want to manipulate the first 255 characters, the string field would probably be more efficient, if you needed to manipulate the entire field, then memo is the way to go.

Answer (score 1):

Like vice said, if you use sql datatype `text` or `varchar(>255)` Crystal Reports, (or at least CR 2013) will treat it as a `memo`

I'm only adding my answer because I found another difference. You cannot group by `memo` fields.